# Extending partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to extend my current Windows partition because it has too little space currently. I was triple-booting Windows Kali and Ubuntu but deleted Kali and now have 93GB left. I cannot assign it to Windows for some reason. I have tried extending Windows' partition from within Windows itself and Ubuntu's Gparted.
**TL;DR: Unallocated space stuck in extended partition, but I want to extend my NTFS/windows partition.**

Ubuntu:
[image: Ubuntu GParted]

Windows:
[image: Windows Disk Manager]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I fixed it. I'll explain for anyone that might ever come across this. On the GParted screenshot you see /dev/sdb/ extended has a key/lock infront of it. When I clicked info it said the following: `Status: Busy (At least one logical partition is mounted)`

Alright. It was because I was booted into my Ubuntu. I burned [GParted on a Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and booted that. It allowed me to shrink the extended partition and resize the windows/ntfs one.